# excel distribute hours value on time plan

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

I want to distribute hours of task on basis of start date and end date considering 9 hours a day. In attachmnet you can see example which is manually filled. Is there any formula which can give this kind of result.

Comment: Vote to close as this is not a software development question, and would probably be better asked on SuperUser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following formula in first cell (`E3` in my sample) and copy to the right and down:

```
=MIN(IF((COLUMN()>5)*(E$1>=$C3),$B3-SUM(D3:$E3),$B3),9*(E$1>=$C3)*(E$1<=$D3))
```

[image]

use number formatting to hide zeros, if you want

Answer (score 0):

You need to be able to find the beginning and the ending date. For that, you might use a `Match()` function. Once you have this, the following can help you:

- Once you are on the most left cell (the one equal to the beginning date), the value should be `MIN(<Hours>,9)`: if the value in the `<Hours>` is smaller than 9, then use that value, otherwise use 9.
- When you are somewhere at the right of that most left cell, the value should be based on `current_cell_attempt = <Hours> - sum(Most_Left_Cell:Adjacent_Cell)`: if this value is larger than 9 then put 9; if it's smaller then put the value.
- Once you start having 0 values, put blanks.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

My formula in E5 is:

```
=IF(AND(E$3>=$C5;E$3<=$D5);MIN(9;$B5-IF(COLUMN()>5;SUM(D5:$E5);0));0)
```

You can drag to right and down. Notice the part `COLUMN()>5` because data starts at column E. If you put this formula somewhere else, you ned to update the `5` properly.